# gnuradio , SDR usrpx300

Tags: sampling, bandwidth, gnuradio, software-defined-radio, usrp

I use usrp x300 SDR.

I'm confused about `Bandwidth` and `sample_rate`. How do I calculate
them? is `sample_rate` = `Bandwidth`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: 2- About Low Pass Filtre block on gnuradio ,how i can calculate transition width and
cuttoff frequency could you please give me example?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm confused about Bandwidth and sample_rate. How i do calculate them? is sample_rate = Bandwidth?

Sample rate: This is a design parameter, not usually something you caclculate, but a requirement that you *define* from what you want to be doing. You set the sample rate of the USRP such that it sufficiently high for your application.

The Bandwidth field in the USRP blocks means the bandwidth of the analog front end. This is not configurable in most daughterboards you can plug into the X300, so just leave it empty.

Comment: 2- About Low Pass Filtre ,how i can calculate transition width and
cutt off frequency could you please give me example?